# Set title for each terminal tab in gnome-terminal using a bash script

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

I want to open multiple terminal tabs, run commands and set title. I can open multiple tabs with this command:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "command1" --tab -e "command2"
```

but cannot use `--title` option as it is not available in this version.

I know `mate-terminal` can do this, but I want to use gnome-terminal.

I've applied solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04#774543) and it worked but when i run

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'set-title 99;ping 192.168.7.99'"
```

It shows:

```
bash: set-title: command not found
PING 192.168.7.99 (192.168.7.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.7.99: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.425 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.99: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.353 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.99: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.335 ms
```

I also applied [the solution suggested here on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320734/call-a-bashrc-function-from-a-bash-shell-script)

I've also read this post [setting-terminal-tab-titles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446041/setting-terminal-tab-titles) but the accepted answer did not solve my issue in 16.04 os or gnome-terminal version 3.18.3 and other solution provides to use other terminal `xterm` and I want to use gnome-terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Terminal tab titles](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446041/setting-terminal-tab-titles)

Comment: Please note, that the core of the problem was that OP wanted to use a function defined in `~/.bashrc` within custom script. Thus, the question is only tangentially related to the link John N provided.  IMHO this is not a strict duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a function stored in `~/.bashrc` then source that file in your command:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc;set-title 99;ping 192.168.7.99'"
```

You've mentioned in the comments that you plan to use this in a shell script and with multiple `gnome-terminal` tabs. As a proof of concept, you can use the following script as example:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST1\007\"; sleep 7'" \
               --tab -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST2\007\"; ping -c 4 8.8.8.8'" \
```

Instead of bash function, this uses `printf` and escape sequences directly. Please be mindful of the backslashes.

Comment: It opens terminal, run command but not set title.

Comment: @Lucy try this function instead : `setTitle() {
 echo -e "\033]0;$@\007" 
} `

Comment: means to put this in .bashrc file & remove that old function?

Comment: @Lucy yes. Or you can put both there, just use different names.  I just tested it with my own gnome-terminal, works. http://imgur.com/a/Dto82

Comment: put that line, closed and open terminal. It says `bash: /home/lucy/.bashrc: line 120: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @Lucy  interesting. did you put that as the last line ?  Try putting it on the top. Also, break it down into 3 lines. I've posted a more-formatted  example of the function on the same post that you referenced. See http://askubuntu.com/a/860497/295286

Comment: To use `setTitle() { echo -e "\033]0;$@\007" }` in .bashrc worked for me

Comment: @Lucy perfect ! Well, congrats , we've solved your question. Also final note: you don't have to use it as function, you probably could simply use `echo -e "\033]0;TITLE TEXT\007"` in your `gnome-terminal command directly. I will make a small addition to my answer, please see it later. Thx

Comment: Yes. Thank you but i have to use it in bash script where title will be used as variable (`setTitle $i`) and will be opened multiple tab and run command so this is perfect for me.

Comment: @Lucy perfect ! that means my addition might be helpful to you. Please see it

Comment: I think you should also provide the function in answer that worked for me.

Comment: printf and escape sequences is ugly and error-prone.     http://askubuntu.com/a/774543/455406  works for bash

Comment: @WillC  Funny thing is that you said it's error prone, yet you link to answer which also uses escape sequences  :) .  On the other hand,  `printf` is more portable than `echo`, because users might not necessarily be using `bash` as a shell, and each shell has its own `echo` implementation.

Comment: Thanks: I wasn't clear, and I was generalising my lack of familiarity with escape codes.  I meant that typing a printf inline each time is error-prone for me because I'm not skilled with escape codes.   If I create that _bash-specific_ '[set-title](http://askubuntu.com/a/774543/455406)' function in my ~/custom_functions.conf, I don't have to re-type any more escape sequences, and so I'm assessing that answer as less error-prone because it reduces the number of escape sequences that I have to type, reducing mis-types that I will make.

Comment: @WillC oh, you're absolutely right - turning a set of commands into functions is very frequent and one of the best practices.