# How can I make terminal tabs persist so I don't have to set everything up again every time?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, productivity

When I'm developing software I normally have one terminal with various tabs open running different things, as an example one of them is running foo

[image]

whilst the other running boo

[image]

This is fine until I power down my PC and the layout is lost. This leads me to have a daily fumble around as I try to get to get everything setup. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: I would recommend you install `terminator`. Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thats about terminal size not about the tabs it has open.

Comment: Ah, you mean specifically tabs, my bad.

Comment: I'm not totall sure, what you are up to, but it sounds as if [devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) could be helpful..

Comment: Hi, @DrGoat , posted an answer, please see. Let me know if you have any additional questions or edits that you'd like me to make.

Comment: easy, switch to a mac and use iterm2, which remrmbers.

Comment: Question, is there a posibility to hold the running of the next script? This because I have some services that have to be started before the next script can run. Hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to automate it via `-t` and `-e` flags to `gnome-terminal`.

For instance, here's a script I've used quite recently for [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/860484/295286) question:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST1\007\"; sleep 7'" \
               --tab -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST2\007\"; ping -c 4 8.8.8.8'"
```

What happens there is that there will be launched `gnome-terminal` window with two tabs , and each will run its own command. The rest is simple - open Startup Applications and add that script as one of the commands to be launched upon logging-in. Remember to make the script executable and give full path to script as a command.

Comment: The tabs automatically close after the command is done :/

Comment: @DrGoat you want to keep the tabs open ?  In that case make it `-e "bash -c 'foo; bash'" That way once command is done, it will drop to new instance of shell. Unlike other terminals, gnome-terminal doesn't have "hold window" option, so you have to use a bit of trickery to keep it open

Comment: @serg `gnome-terminal` has a "hold window" option. Go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> When command exits -> set to "Hold the terminal open".

Comment: @wjandrea That causes often unintended side effects though, e.g. you can no longer close a terminal window by exiting the shell with `exit` or CTRL+D.