# How to force PS1 to evaluate so I can use terminal title as a status bar?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I wanted to use the set-title function from https://askubuntu.com/a/774543/435408 to make the terminal title into a sort of status bar. That way I can see in the GUI whether my server is Running or Complete.

```
set-title Running && doStuff.sh && set-title Complete
```

With this code, you never see the title change to "Running", only "Complete". I believe this is because the title only changes when the system reads PS1 to make a new prompt, after all three commands run.

I got "Running" to show right away by putting the other commands in the background:

```
doStuff.sh && set-title Complete & set-title Running; fg
```

But then the terminal title was never set to "Complete" because that call was in the background. "fg" didn't help.

I had similar problems with

```
set-title Running; echo "doStuff.sh; set-title Complete" | at now + 0 minutes
```

Finally, I tried opening a new terminal tab titled "Running", as per https://askubuntu.com/a/860484/435408, but I was not able to pass any commands to the bash session to set its title to "Complete". The tab closes right away if I try using --rcfile or -c.

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;Running\007\"; sleep 4; exec bash'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the behavior I wanted like this:

1. Use `gnome-terminal` to create a window with the "Running" title
2. Keep the window open after execution by calling `exec bash`
3. Put the call to "set-title Complete" in a file called `~/.statusrc` which I passed to the new bash.

```
gnome-terminal --maximize --title="Running" -- /usr/bin/bash -c \
". /home/user/.bashrc; doStuff.sh; exec bash --rcfile /home/user/.statusrc"
```

The ~/.statusrc file looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

. ~/.bashrc
termtitle "Complete"
```